# Convert Single String to Nested List Array

Tags: c#, list, split

String value = "**71.08099899999999,24.10229 // 71.08099899999999,24.102665 /// 71.080874,24.10279 // 71.080749,24.102915** ";

To Nested Array List

```
List<List<List<decimal>>> Arr = [
    [
        [
            [71.08099899999999][24.10229]
        ][
            [71.08099899999999][24.102665]
        ]
    ][
        [
            [71.080874][24.10279]
        ][
            [71.080749][24.102915]
        ]
    ]
];
```

what I had tried utill now:

```
List<List<string>> val1 = new List<List<string>>();
List<List<List<string>>> val2 = new List<List<List<string>>>();

string[] val = value .Split(new string[] { " /// " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
for (int i = 0; i < val.Length - 1; i++)
{
    val1.Add(val[i].Split(new string[] { " // " }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList());
}

for (int i = 0; i < val1.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < val1[i].Count-1; i++) { }
}
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried.

Comment: i Can do tried the above solution, but is there any fastest way to achieve the above problem solution in c#

Comment: To be honest, this is ugly. I would create a class for your data, or at least use *Tuples*.

Comment: List<List<List<decimal>>> ??? it's the ugliest staff I've ever seen, rethink what are you doing, sure there is a better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.Split` and linq `.Select`:

```
var result = value.Split(new[] { "///" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Select(lvl1 =>
                lvl1.Split(new[] { "//" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Select(lvl2 =>
                    lvl2.Split(',').Select(val => 
                        decimal.Parse(val.Trim())).ToList()).ToList()).ToList();
```

*Notice that this will fail if one of the values is not a valid decimal. To ensure you can project a `decimal?` and use `decimal.TryParse` and then `Select` only non null items*

As a side note.. having so many nested collections seems like a design smell. Consider thinking about a different design

Comment: Thank u so much @giladgreen